# SVG > Animate width from middle

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, web

I got a logo in SVG that I want to animate.
There is a middle part that will remain fixed but the sides strokes will actually expands and get around the whole thing. There is and exemple of what i want to do actually:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <style type="text/css">
  .st0{fill:#656E76;}
 </style>
 <g>
  <rect id="rect1" class="st0" cx="50" cy="50" x="0" y="40.5" width="158.9" height="6.3"/>
  <rect id="rect2" class="st0" cx="0" cy="100" x="0" y="6.4" width="6.3" height="34.4"/>
  <rect id="rect3" class="st0" cx="0" cy="100" x="152.6" y="6.4" width="6.3" height="34.4"/>
  <rect id="rect4" class="st0" cx="0" cy="0" x="0" y="0.2" width="38.8" height="6.3"/>
  <rect id="rect5" class="st0" cx="100" cy="0" x="120.2" y="0.2" width="38.8" height="6.3"/>
  
  <animate xlink:href="#rect1" attributeName="width" from="0" to="158.9" begin="0s" dur="0.4s" />
  <animate xlink:href="#rect2" attributeName="height" from="0" to="34.4"  begin="0.4s" dur="0.25s" />
  <animate xlink:href="#rect3" attributeName="height" from="0" to="34.4" begin="0.4s" dur="0.25s" />
  <animate xlink:href="#rect4" attributeName="width" from="0" to="38.5" begin="0.65s" dur="0.25s" />
  <animate xlink:href="#rect5" attributeName="width" from="0" to="38.5" begin="0.65s" dur="0.25s" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

At the moment, the animation kind of work but I could not make my object expanding from their correct center. By exemple the bottom line should expand from its middle, the side lines should expand from the bottom etc.

Need help about that. Can someone lend a hand please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you aren't wedded to using rectangles to form the sides of your shape, then it becomes a much easier problem if you change your shape to using a single path with stroke width equivalent to your rectangle thickness.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <g>
        <path id="shape" fill="none" stroke-width="6.3" stroke="#656E76"
              d="M 38.8 3.35 H 3.15 V 43.65 H 155.75 V 3.35 H 120.2" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

You can then implement your animation by animating the dash pattern of the line.  Imagine your path length is 100. We want to start with a 0 length dash and then end with a dash  of 100.  At the same time, we animate the dash offset (where the dash pattern starts) from -50 (shifts the dash pattern to the centre of the line) to 0 (the start of the line).

For our line, the path length is actually 304.4. So the final animation becomes:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <g>
        <path id="shape" fill="none" stroke-width="6.3" stroke="#656E76"
              d="M 38.8 3.35 H 3.15 V 43.65 H 155.75 V 3.35 H 120.2" />
  <animate xlink:href="#shape" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" from="0 304.4" to="304.4 0" begin="0s" dur="0.4s" />
  <animate xlink:href="#shape" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="-152.2" to="0" begin="0s" dur="0.4s" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

Aside: we could also achieve the same effect by just animating the dash pattern alone, but how this works takes longer to explain :)

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <g>
        <path id="shape" fill="none" stroke-width="6.3" stroke="#656E76"
              d="M 38.8 3.35 H 3.15 V 43.65 H 155.75 V 3.35 H 120.2" />
 <animate xlink:href="#shape" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" from="0 152.2 0 152.2" to="0 0 304.4 0" begin="0s" dur="0.4s" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Fantastic that is even better! Thanks, that is the best answer I could have!