# SVG layout properties

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to place separate SVG code at the bottom inline but am unsure as to how as this differs from usual HTML layout properties.

I have wrapped each SVG in a common div as shown:

```css
    .svg-container {
     width: 60px;
     display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="svg-container">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 128 128">
    <path fill="#E44D26" d="M27.854 116.354l-8.043-90.211h88.378l-8.051 
    90.197-36.192 10.033z"></path><path fill="#F16529" d="M64 
    118.704l29.244-8.108 6.881-77.076h-36.125z"></path><path fill="#EBEBEB" 
    d="M64 66.978h-14.641l-1.01-11.331h15.651v-11.064h-27.743l.264 2.969 
    2.72 30.489h24.759zM64 95.711l-.049.013-12.321-3.328-.788-8.823h-
    11.107l1.55 17.372 22.664 6.292.051-.015z"></path><path d="M28.034 
    1.627h5.622v5.556h5.144v-5.556h5.623v16.822h-5.623v-5.633h-
    5.143v5.633h-
    5.623v-16.822zM51.816 7.206h-4.95v-5.579h15.525v5.579h-4.952v11.243h-
    5.623v-11.243zM64.855 1.627h5.862l3.607 5.911 3.603-
    5.911h5.865v16.822h-
    5.601v-8.338l-3.867 5.981h-.098l-3.87-5.981v8.338h-5.502v-
    16.822zM86.591 
    1.627h5.624v11.262h7.907v5.561h-13.531v-16.823z"></path><path 
    fill="#fff" d="M63.962 66.978v11.063h13.624l-1.284 14.349-12.34 
    3.331v11.51l22.682-6.286.166-1.87 2.6-29.127.27-2.97h-2.982zM63.962 
    44.583v11.064h26.725l.221-2.487.505-5.608.265-2.969z"></path>
    </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="svg-container">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 128 128">
    <path fill="#F0DB4F" d="M1.408 1.408h125.184v125.185h-125.184z"></path>
    <path fill="#323330" d="M116.347 96.736c-.917-5.711-4.641-10.508-
    15.672-
    14.981-3.832-1.761-8.104-3.022-9.377-5.926-.452-1.69-.512-2.642-.226-
    3.665.821-3.32 4.784-4.355 7.925-3.403 2.023.678 3.938 2.237 5.093 
    4.724 
    5.402-3.498 5.391-3.475 9.163-5.879-1.381-2.141-2.118-3.129-3.022-
    4.045-
    3.249-3.629-7.676-5.498-14.756-5.355l-3.688.477c-3.534.893-6.902 2.748-
    8.877 5.235-5.926 6.724-4.236 18.492 2.975 23.335 7.104 5.332 17.54 
    6.545 18.873 11.531 1.297 6.104-4.486 8.08-10.234 7.378-4.236-.881-
    6.592-3.034-9.139-6.949-4.688 2.713-4.688 2.713-9.508 5.485 1.143 2.499 
    2.344 3.63 4.26 5.795 9.068 9.198 31.76 8.746 35.83-5.176.165-.478 
    1.261-3.666.38-8.581zm-46.885-37.793h-11.709l-.048 30.272c0 6.438.333 
    12.34-.714 14.149-1.713 3.558-6.152 3.117-8.175 2.427-2.059-1.012-
    3.106-
    2.451-4.319-4.485-.333-.584-.583-1.036-.667-1.071l-9.52 5.83c1.583 
    3.249 
    3.915 6.069 6.902 7.901 4.462 2.678 10.459 3.499 16.731 2.059 4.082-
    1.189 7.604-3.652 9.448-7.401 2.666-4.915 2.094-10.864 2.07-17.444.06-
    10.735.001-21.468.001-32.237z"></path>
    </svg>
    </div>
```

If I adjust the coordinates in the viewbox to correlate with `viewBox = <min-x> <min-y> <width> <height>` such as `<svg viewBox="0 -250 128 128">` the position doesn't change.

Any help with someone with svg experience would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does "at the bottom inline" mean exactly?  Please elaborate. Consider perhaps adding a picture to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there are two questions here, I'll try to answer both; my understanding is that you would like to:

1. Have two inline columns, each with an SVG in them that scales to the width of their respective column on resize.
2. Move the paths of the SVGs within the view box.

Regarding 1, to do this, you can set `viewBox = "0 0 widthOfSVG heightOfSVG"`. Then just use CSS to set the columns adjacent to each other. Importantly, this will not work in many versions of IE – the simplest work around there is often to use javascript to resize your SVGs by binding a function to the window resize event.

For 2, unfortunately, I believe the paths need to be recomputed / rewritten to the correct location on the SVG. While this could be done with JavaScript, it's liable to become fairly involved quickly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Apparently, you tried to delete the text "HTML" above the Html5 logo
   in the SVG file and erased the extra part of the path. I took the
   original HTML5 logo svg file and added the css markup.
2. The "JS" logo was not in the center of the `viewport`. For the
   location of JS characters in the center of the `viewport` added:

`width="100" height="100" viewBox="12 25 128 128"`

The first two attributes of the `viewBox` shift the JS characters to the left and up to 12px and 25px respectively.

If I correctly understood your question, it should look like this:

```css
.svg-container {
position:absolute;
 top:2%; 
 left:1%;
 width: 120px;
 display: inline-block;
 }
.svg-container2 {
 position:absolute;
 top:16%; 
 left:20%;
 width: 60px;
 display: inline-block;

}
.wrap {
width:1000px;
height:120px;
position:relative;
padding:0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="svg-container">
<svg  viewBox="0 0 512 512">
 <title>HTML5 Logo</title>
 <polygon fill="#E44D26" points="107.644,470.877 74.633,100.62 437.367,100.62 404.321,470.819 255.778,512"/>
 <polygon fill="#F16529" points="256,480.523 376.03,447.246 404.27,130.894 256,130.894"/>
 <polygon fill="#EBEBEB" points="256,268.217 195.91,268.217 191.76,221.716 256,221.716 256,176.305 255.843,176.305 142.132,176.305 143.219,188.488 154.38,313.627 256,313.627"/>
 <polygon fill="#EBEBEB" points="256,386.153 255.801,386.206 205.227,372.55 201.994,336.333 177.419,336.333 156.409,336.333 162.771,407.634 255.791,433.457 256,433.399"/>
 <path d="M108.382,0h23.077v22.8h21.11V0h23.078v69.044H152.57v-23.12h-21.11v23.12h-23.077V0z"/>
 <path d="M205.994,22.896h-20.316V0h63.72v22.896h-20.325v46.148h-23.078V22.896z"/>
 <path d="M259.511,0h24.063l14.802,24.26L313.163,0h24.072v69.044h-22.982V34.822l-15.877,24.549h-0.397l-15.888-24.549v34.222h-22.58V0z"/>
 <path d="M348.72,0h23.084v46.222h32.453v22.822H348.72V0z"/>
 <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="255.843,268.217 255.843,313.627 311.761,313.627 306.49,372.521 255.843,386.191 255.843,433.435 348.937,407.634 349.62,399.962 360.291,280.411 361.399,268.217 349.162,268.217"/>
 <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="255.843,176.305 255.843,204.509 255.843,221.605 255.843,221.716 365.385,221.716 365.385,221.716 365.531,221.716 366.442,211.509 368.511,188.488 369.597,176.305"/>
</svg>
</div>
<div class="svg-container2">
<svg    width="100" height="100" viewBox="12 25 128 128" style="border:1px solid black">
<rect x="12" y="25" width="128" height="128" fill="#F0DB4F"    />
<path fill="#F0DB4F"  d="M1.408 1.408h125.184v125.185h-125.184z"></path>
<path fill="#323330" stroke="none" d="M116.347 96.736c-.917-5.711-4.641-10.508-15.672-14.981-3.832-1.761-8.104-3.022-9.377-5.926-.452-1.69-.512-2.642-.226-3.665.821-3.32 4.784-4.355 7.925-3.403 2.023.678 3.938 2.237 5.093 4.724 
5.402-3.498 5.391-3.475 9.163-5.879-1.381-2.141-2.118-3.129-3.022-4.045-3.249-3.629-7.676-5.498-14.756-5.355l-3.688.477c-3.534.893-6.902 2.748-8.877 5.235-5.926 6.724-4.236 18.492 2.975 23.335 7.104 5.332 17.54 6.545 18.873 11.531 1.297 6.104-4.486 8.08-10.234 7.378-4.236-.881-6.592-3.034-9.139-6.949-4.688 2.713-4.688 2.713-9.508 5.485 1.143 2.499 
2.344 3.63 4.26 5.795 9.068 9.198 31.76 8.746 35.83-5.176.165-.478 
1.261-3.666.38-8.581zm-46.885-37.793h-11.709l-.048 30.272c0 6.438.333 
12.34-.714 14.149-1.713 3.558-6.152 3.117-8.175 2.427-2.059-1.012-3.106-2.451-4.319-4.485-.333-.584-.583-1.036-.667-1.071l-9.52 5.83c1.583 3.249 3.915 6.069 6.902 7.901 4.462 2.678 10.459 3.499 16.731 2.059 4.082-1.189 7.604-3.652 9.448-7.401 2.666-4.915 2.094-10.864 2.07-17.444.06-10.735.001-21.468.001-32.237z">
</path>
</svg>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Those two namespace declarationa are **not** needed if the SVG is embedded inline in the HTML.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thank you for the valuable clarification. Now I will edit. I really like your answers to questions. For example, I admired this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37632648/7394871

Comment: .@Alexandr_T You only removed one of the two. Your statement "To add svg directly to Html, you need to add namespaces XML." is not correct.